# Rollback snapshot but run out of space

Tags: rollback, snapshot, zfs

I have a 1TB zpool and a 700GB volume with one clean snapshot, such as:

```
zpool1
zpool1/volume1
zpool1/volume1@snap1
```

After writing 500GB data into volume, its written property has growth to 500GB as well.

Then I tried to rollback to the snapshot and I got error with "out of space".

Does zpool need extra space to rollback snapshot with big written value? Or can anyone explain why it fails?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After searching of zfs source code(dsl_dataset.c), I found the last part of dsl_dataset_rollback_check() may explain this limit:

```
 * When we do the clone swap, we will temporarily use more space
 * due to the refreservation (the head will no longer have any
 * unique space, so the entire amount of the refreservation will need
 * to be free).  We will immediately destroy the clone, freeing
 * this space, but the freeing happens over many txg's.
 *
unused_refres_delta = (int64_t)MIN(ds->ds_reserved,
    dsl_dataset_phys(ds)->ds_unique_bytes);

if (unused_refres_delta > 0 &&
    unused_refres_delta >
    dsl_dir_space_available(ds->ds_dir, NULL, 0, TRUE)) {
    dsl_dataset_rele(ds, FTAG);
    return (SET_ERROR(ENOSPC));
}
```

So that the volume's "avail" must be lager than "refreserv" to perform rollback.
Only for thin-volume can pass this check.

Answer (score 1):

Rolling back to a snapshot requires a little space (for updating metadata), but this is very small.

From what you’ve described, I would expect nearly anything you write in the same pool / quota group to fail with `ENOSPC` at this point. If you run `zpool status`, I bet you’ll see that the entire pool is almost entirely full, or if you are using quotas, perhaps you’ve eaten up all of whatever quota group it applies to. If this is not what you expected, it could be that you’re using mirroring or RAID-Z, which causes duplicate bytes to be written (to allow corruption recovery). You can tell this by looking at the `used` physical bytes (instead of `written` logical bytes) in `zfs list`.

Most of the data you added after the snapshot can be deleted once rollback has completed, but not before then (so rollback has to keep that data around until it completes).

Comment: Thanks Dan, the rollback has to keep data just as you said. I have checked zfs source code and made some test to verify it.